# Remove comma from NSMutableArray elements

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am adding objects (NSArray type) from my service url to a NSMutableArray named slots. The structure of slots is as followS:

```
SLOTS=(
       (
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "12_30",
       "13_00",
       "13_30",
       "14_00",
       "14_30"
       ),
       (
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "12_30",
       "13_00",
       "13_30",
       "14_00",
       "14_30"
       ),
       (
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "12_30",
       "13_00",
       "13_30",
       "14_00",
       "14_30"
       ),
       (
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "12_30",
       "13_00",
       "13_30",
       "14_00",
       "14_30"
       ),
       (
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "--:--",
       "12_30",
       "13_00",
       "13_30",
       "14_00",
       "14_30"
       )
     )
```

I am successfully able to access array & show its contents on buttons.

i need to check for " _ " and show time after that on my button.

Comment: "My problem is i need to check for " _ " and replace it by ":"" - then this is probably an `NSString` question and as such, is not related to arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [slots count]; i++) {

        NSArray *array = [slots objectAtIndex:i];
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *aString in array) {

            NSString *newString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@":"];
            [newArray addObject:newString];
        }
        [slots replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newArray];
}
```

Here 'slots' is the array that holds all data.

Comment: Dont spoon feed , let them code

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSMutableArray *slots=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array];
for (NSObject *obect in slots)
{
    for (NSString *string in (NSArray*)obect)
    {
        [slots addObject:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@":"]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"pathArr %@ ",  slots);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can do :-

```
NSArray *arr=@[@"--:--",@"--:--"];
NSMutableArray *mutableArr=[NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *str in arr)
{
    NSString *str1=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@":"];
    [mutableArr addObject:str1];
}
NSLog(@"%@",mutableArr);
```